# XLib Error when compiling QT for ARM using linux-arm-gnueabi-g++

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, arm, qmake

I am having some issues compiling a QT program from an i386 Ubuntu Linux PC to a Pandaboard.

We were successful in creating a build which could create a console application from my PC to a Pandaboard, but when I try to use a program with a GUI, I receive a missing symbol error.

We are trying to build a program which runs directly on the Ubuntu system on the ARM device.

We do not want to run the program as embedded, but as a stand-alone QT application.

I am having an issue with the X11 Display Drivers I believe.

**Below is the error I am receiving when running my ./configure:**

XLib functionality test failed!  You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 and QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 in /home/vantage/QT_ARM_GUI2/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++.

**Below are the items I have installed on the current build:**

```
libfontconfig1-dev

libfreetype6-dev

libx11-dev

libxcursor-dev

libxext-dev

libxfixes-dev

libxft-dev

libxi-dev

libxrandr-dev

libxrender-dev

sudo apt-get install build-essential automake autoconf libtool

sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi

sudo apt-get build-dep qt4-qmake
```

**Below is my current PATH variable:**

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/vantage/QT/arm-2012.09/bin:/home/vantage/QT/xc/include/X11:/home/vantage/QT/xc/lib/X11:/usr/lib/xorg:/usr/include/xorg
```

**I am using the following build of QT:**

qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4

**I am using the below toolchain:**

arm-2012.09-64-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu from codesourcery

**Below is my Config statement:**

```
./configure -arch arm -nomake demos - nomake examples - nomake docs -no-qt3support -release -platform linux-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -declarative -xmlpatterns -exceptions -make tools -make libs -little-endian
```

I have edited my linux.conf file and changed the QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 to point to /usr/lib/xorg and my QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 to /usr/include/xorg.

I have also edited my linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -> qmake.conf file to match the above include and lib directories.

I have also tried to point these directories to the library and include files I received from "http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/src-single/X11R6.8.1-src.tar.bz2" which I exported to home/vantage/QT/xc/.

I have been following the below article, attempting to work through the errors but I am still receiving the issue with Xlib.
"http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17193"

Any direction or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to provide all these installed libs i.e. libX11 etc. in qmake.config file in Qt source.
once you include cross compiled libs and headers then it should work.